# TCPDF can see line in pdf generated but not in printout

Tags: php, tcpdf

```
$style = array('width' => 0.5, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(255, 0, 0));

$pdf->Line(5, 10, 80, 30, $style);
```

I uses the above statements to draw a line.
Result view in screen has this line drawn.
However It's not printed on paper.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry folks, it's not TCPDF problem.
I was using Google to print out the PDF generated and having this problem.
If I try Internet Explorer there is no problem.